# detect if view has been scrolled outof the screen in react native

Tags: react-native, scrollview, react-native-ios

I want to show some other View (A), when a View (B) already present in the screen within the scrollview, is not visible on the screen.
In short, show View A when View B is not visible on the screen, in react native.
How can i do so, without installing any third party library?

Answer (score 0):

You can make it very simply
Set a state which can be something you can access and change
for example

```
const [viewToShow, setViewToShow'] = React.useState("A");
```

Then in the return block just do

```
{{ viewToShow === "A" && ( <ViewA /> ) }}
{{ viewToSHow === "B" && ( <ViewB /> ) }}
```

And have maybe a button that wil help you to switch the value of `viewToShow`

Comment: This answer makes no sense to me. Can you elaborate?

Comment: How can i achieve it using the scrollview and view position?